# How to filter custom protocol packet?

Tags: c, filter, winpcap

I want to set filter, of "ether type" which value is equal to `0xe188`. 
How to write this filter?

My filter is `"ether type 0xe188"`, but it compiles with ERROR:

```
if(pcap_compile(fp, &fcode,"ether proto 0xe188", 1, NetMask) >= 0)
    pcap_setfilter(fp, &fcode);
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for this is [`ether proto`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/pcap-filter).

Comment: "ether proto 0xe188" is not work,how to write this filter string?

Comment: @GuyHarris no error but there is nothing data after set this filter

Comment: If you get rid of the filter, and have your program explicitly check the Ethernet type (the 12th and 13th bytes of an Ethernet packet, in big-endian byte order), does it see any packets with an Ethernet type of 0xe188?  If not, there is no data after the filter is set because there are no packets with an Ethernet type of 0xe188.

Comment: Also check type 0x88e1. Endianity is confusing.